# write all users input data on csv file in jmeter beanshell PostProcessor with non repeated users?

Tags: java, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

When i use CSV Data Set for the input data during load testing with thread group as 10 users for creating account scenario, I want to save all users data who has created there accounts again on a different CSV file.
but, the each thread group always overwrite the file and i end up with a file that contains the same data repeated 10 times line by line.

this is my code in BeanShell PostProcessor script:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.List;
File f=new File("C:\\apache-jmeter-5.3\\apache-jmeter-5.3\\bin\\CSVfiles\\test1.csv");
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f);
BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);


int threadnum=ctx.getThreadNum();

 for (int i =-1; i < threadnum; i++)
   {
    
String searchAddr = vars.get("firstname");

    
String searchAddr2 = vars.get("lastname");


bw.write(searchAddr);
bw.write(",");
bw.write(searchAddr2);
bw.write("\n");

   }
bw.close();
fw.close();
```

this is the content of the csv file after the test:

```
firstname3, lastname3
firstname3, lastname3
firstname3, lastname3
```

what i want is :

```
firstname1, lastname1
firstname2, lastname2
firstname3, lastname3
```

can you guys help me with the code so i can get non repeated data?

Answer (score 0):

If all your 10 virtual users are writing the same data my expectation is that you can amend your code to write the data for only one user, i.e. the first one like:

```
File f = new File("C:\\apache-jmeter-5.3\\apache-jmeter-5.3\\bin\\CSVfiles\\test1.csv");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);


int threadnum = ctx.getThreadNum();
if (threadnum == 0) { // write data to file only for the first user

    for (int i = -1; i < threadnum; i++) {

        String searchAddr = vars.get("firstname");


        String searchAddr2 = vars.get("lastname");


        bw.write(searchAddr);
        bw.write(",");
        bw.write(searchAddr2);
        bw.write("\n");

    }
}
bw.close();
fw.close();
```

A couple more pieces of advice:

1. [Starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), you can even re-use the same code, it will work much faster
2. If you will be writing data into the same file with > 1 user at a time you will run into a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) resulting in data corruption, going forward consider using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) for this purposes